# How to use Cubic Hermite and Cubic Spline to interpolate Sine(x) with 4-5 non uniform samples?

Tags: c, interpolation, numerical-methods, bgi

Task is to draw a curve of Sin(x) and then use Cubic Hermite and Cubic Spline to interpolate the sine wave with 4-5 non-uniform samples.

I've written a code to draw a sine wave but now I'm stuck how to implement the cubic (Hermite and Spline interpolation).

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

initwindow(800,600);
int x,y;
line(0,300,getmaxx(),300);
line(400,0,400,getmaxy());
float pi = 3.14;

for(int i = -360; i < 360 ; i++){

x = (int) 400+i;
y = (int) 300 - sin(i*pi/100)*25;
putpixel(x,y,WHITE);

}

getch();
closegraph();

return 0;

}
```

> Expected result is to calculate Cubic Hermite and Cubic Spline interpolation on the sine(x) wave.

Comment: First thing to do: indent your code (like the samples in your C text book).

Comment: Then show your attempt. There is no attempt other than drawing a plain sinusoide.

Comment: If you are using `std::sin`, note that it requires an angle in radians, try `i*pi/180.0`.

Comment: Do you plan to rely on a library or do you need to implement from scratch ?

Comment: Your next task is to implement the drawing of a cubic Bezier curve, given four control points. This will be used in both Hermite and Spline interpolations.